# A double integral question about finding volume of a segment of cylinder

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

The question: The segment of the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ bounded above by the plane z = 12 + x + y and below by z = 0.

So, I tried to solve the question and got this:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} 12+x+y \,dy\,dx$$ = 37.6991 which equals 12$\pi$

the book says the answer is 12$\pi$ but I don't know how I can solve the question and get the answers in terms of $\pi$. I know the base is $\pi$ but how I can use it to solve the question.

If I expand my question, in case of knowing the area of something, can use it to find the volume etc. For example:

$\int f(x,y)  dA$ and If I know dA is $\pi$, can I use it somehow?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} (12+x+y) \,dy\,dx=\underbrace{\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} (x+y) \,dy\,dx}_{0}+12\underbrace{\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}  \,dy\,dx}_{1\times 1\times\pi}=12\pi$$ 
Because the region of Integration is symmetric about all two axes and $f(x,y)=x+y$ is an odd function in the variables $x$ and $y$ , so the value of the integral is $0$

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to integrate. Imagine a z=12 plane cutting off the top of the shape. The piece cut off will fit neatly between the z=12 plane and the remaining shape. 12pi.